# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-5

I am trying to get data from a component to another via service but I'm not able to get past this error :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'statistics')
    at StatsComponent_div_2_Template
```

I've tried multiple different implementations, for example removing the type when declaring my variable and adding the ? operator in the HTML, it removes the error but never returns anything. Can anyone tell me why please? Here is my code. Regards,

TypeScript component

```
export class StatsComponent implements OnInit {
  myCharactere: ICharactere = this.myService.getPersonnageByName("Xefoul Snaromers");
  statLookup = [

    { key: 'str', prefix: $localize`str`, suffix: $localize`enght`, couleur: 'bg-danger' },
    { key: 'dex', prefix: $localize`dex`, suffix: $localize`terity`, couleur: 'bg-primary' },
    { key: 'con', prefix: $localize`con`, suffix: $localize`stitution`, couleur: 'bg-warning' },
    { key: 'int', prefix: $localize`int`, suffix: $localize`elligence`, couleur: 'bg-success' },
    { key: 'sag', prefix: $localize`wis`, suffix: $localize`dom`, couleur: 'bg-info' },
    { key: 'cha', prefix: $localize`cha`, suffix: $localize`risma`, couleur: 'bg-dark' }
  ];
  constructor(public myService: ServeurService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("mon perso stats", this.myCharactere)
  }
  
  getModifier(stat: number): string {
    const mod = Math.floor((stat-10)/2)
    return (mod<0)?'-':'+'+ mod.toString();
  }
}
```

HTML code

```
<div class="row text-center text-light bg-secondary mt-2  bg-transparent">
    <div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-2" *ngFor="let stat of statLookup">
            <div class="{{stat.couleur}} mx-xxl-4 mx-2 mx-md-1 rounded-4">
                <div class="fw-bold">{{stat.prefix}}<span class="d-none d-lg-inline">{{stat.suffix}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="h2">
                    {{getModifier(myCharactere.statistics[stat.key])}}
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    {{myCharactere.statistics[stat.key]}}
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

TypeScript Service

```
 export class ServeurService {
  token = '';
  serverCharacter = 'https://cegep.fdtt.space/v1/characters';
  serverSecret = 'https://cegep.fdtt.space/v1/secret';
  serverToken = 'https://cegep.fdtt.space/v1/token';
  personnages: any[] = [];
  persoName = '';

  constructor(private http_client: HttpClient) { }

  setPersonnageName(name: string) {
    this.persoName = name;
  }

  getPersonnageName():string {
    return this.persoName;
  }

  getPersonnageByName(name: string) {
    const persoSelectionne = this.getPersonnages().find((n: {name: string; }) => n.name === name);
    return persoSelectionne; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Does myCharactere have any value on ngOnInit? because you will get error if its undefined!

Comment: no, myCharactere has no value on ngOnInit. It should ?

Comment: NgOninit should intialize the value of `myCharactere` Do check my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the HTML error you can do something like this.

```
<div class="row text-center text-light bg-secondary mt-2  bg-transparent">
    <div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-2" *ngFor="let stat of statLookup">
            <div class="{{stat.couleur}} mx-xxl-4 mx-2 mx-md-1 rounded-4">
                <div class="fw-bold">{{stat.prefix}}<span class="d-none d-lg-inline">{{stat.suffix}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="h2">
                    {{myCharactere && myCharactere.statistics && myCharactere.statistics[stat.key] ? getModifier(myCharactere.statistics[stat.key]) : ''}}
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    {{myCharactere && myCharactere.statistics && myCharactere.statistics[stat.key] || ''}}
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also you can initialize the `myCharactere` on the `ngOnInit`

```
export class StatsComponent implements OnInit {
  myCharactere: ICharactere;
  statLookup = [

    { key: 'str', prefix: $localize`str`, suffix: $localize`enght`, couleur: 'bg-danger' },
    { key: 'dex', prefix: $localize`dex`, suffix: $localize`terity`, couleur: 'bg-primary' },
    { key: 'con', prefix: $localize`con`, suffix: $localize`stitution`, couleur: 'bg-warning' },
    { key: 'int', prefix: $localize`int`, suffix: $localize`elligence`, couleur: 'bg-success' },
    { key: 'sag', prefix: $localize`wis`, suffix: $localize`dom`, couleur: 'bg-info' },
    { key: 'cha', prefix: $localize`cha`, suffix: $localize`risma`, couleur: 'bg-dark' }
  ];
  constructor(public myService: ServeurService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.myCharactere = this.myService.getPersonnageByName("Xefoul Snaromers");
    console.log("mon perso stats", this.myCharactere)
  }
  
  getModifier(stat: number): string {
    const mod = Math.floor((stat-10)/2)
    return (mod<0)?'-':'+'+ mod.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: It does remove the error, but it doesn't return anything... What does that mean?

Comment: @PeterSarateanu Could you try the updated answer, please ensure myCharactere has a value only then it will render right?

Comment: I tried your solution and I got the error "Property 'myCharactere' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor." on "myCharactere: ICharactere;" so I added ! on myCharactere but it doesn't return anything still

Comment: @PeterSarateanu Please share the contents of myCharactere also the contents from the API call I mean

Comment: ok, I will post the update shortly

Answer (score 0):

You can try nullish operator(?). because initially myCharactere is undefined.
You can try this way.

```
            <div class="h2">
                {{getModifier(myCharactere?.statistics[stat.key])}}
            </div>
            <div class="">
                {{myCharactere?.statistics[stat.key]}}
            </div>
```

Comment: I get Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.

Comment: Try this one {{myCharactere?.statistics[stat.key]}} instead of {{myCharactere.statistics[stat?.key]}}